# Malloc C and C++ code compatibility

Tags: c++, g++

I have made a program that contains the following function in C:

```
void *e_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *m = malloc(size);

    if (!m)
    {
        printf("Out of memory, fatal error.");
        abort();
    }

    return m;
}
```

I am using this as an `error free malloc` that exits the program when out of memory. The thing is, that when I compile the code in linux with `g++`, I get an error because it says that it needs to be casted, and as you can see I always return a void pointer cause that's what `malloc` returns (`gcc` of course compiles fine). Is there a way I could modify this function to make it work on both compilers ? Do I just have to cast it every time ? Are there other options to make what I am trying to do ?

Also, when I use Cmake (through Clion IDE) the code compiles just fine with `"-std=C++11"`. Why is that ?

[image: 1]

Comment: Pedantic note: `if (!m)` should be `if (!m && size > 0)`

Comment: Is the error thrown in this function? Or when you try to assign the `void*` you return to another pointer (presumably not void). In C void pointers are implicitly cast to other types and in C++ they aren't.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text!

Comment: should be `g = static_cast<graph_t*>( e_malloc( sizeof(graph_t) ) );`

Comment: @RyanP Yes I know that, I just want to know what is the best solution to overcome this issue. Do I have to cast it every single time ? also why did it work on cmake then when I compiled it as a .cpp file with `"-std=C++11"`

Comment: @RyanP to be pedantic: a generic pointer is not implicitly casted, it is assignment compatible to all pointers in C.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. This is apparently C++ related.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need this to be compilable in both C and C++? There are a few valid reasons for it, but they're pretty rare. The normal way to handle this is to just say it's C and needs to be compiled with a C compiler (so only support gcc, not g++)...

Comment: @Olaf yes, the point is that I want this code to work for both C and C++ compilers

Comment: Why not also make it Java and Python compatible? Re-read my comment; no need to repeat myself. You just cannot, because C does not support `static_cast` and C++ does require it. Also, you should not use `malloc` for C++ code. If you have C code, compile with a C compiler, otherwise write C++ code.

Comment: @Shiro You should have to cast every time, I'm not sure it'd make it any easier... I suppose you could make e_malloc a template function so that it returned the correct type, but I'm not sure that's helping your cause too much.

Comment: @RyanP How do you propose to do that while at the same time maintaining C compatibility? :)

Comment: Guys, are you are saying all this? OP **SHOULD NOT** use `*malloc*` in C++ code. Period.

Comment: @hvd I don't, which is why it isn't helping his cause... but it is a way to not have to cast every time :)

Comment: @RyanP, the way to not cast is to not use malloc. What might be simpler?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, your comment made me think something. Is what I am trying to do stupid ? Is it possible to compile one file with gcc and another file with g++ and combine C and C++ in a program that way ?

Comment: @SergeyA In a perfect world I agree, but if you have to use common libraries in your project that are used in other legacy code that you don't have the option of changing.. I don't know what his use case is.

Comment: @Shiro Sure. That's of course a totally different question, but look up `extern "C"`, it allows C++ to use declarations of C functions, that are indeed contained in C source files and compiled with a C compiler.

Comment: @hvd I am already using that in my code

Comment: @Shiro side note, if you are allocating memory from a function declared via `extern "C"`, that allocation is being tracked by a different CRT than your C++ code and if you try to `free()` it in your C++ code you're going to have a bad time. Something to consider.

Comment: @Shiro You don't need anything else to make it work, so it seems like you're good to go, then.

Comment: Decide which language you want to use for a program. There is no benefit, and many drawbacks, to trying to write in two languages simultaneously

Comment: @RyanP Allocating in C with `malloc` and releasing in C++ with `free` is fine. Allocating in C with `malloc` and releasing in C++ with `delete` is a problem. It's only `new` and `delete` that use different memory management code.

Comment: @M.M, I'd say, it is generally impossible. One **should not** cast result of malloc in C (as we all well know), yet the code won't compile in C++ without a cast.

Comment: @Shiro "*Also, when I use Cmake (through Clion IDE) the code compiles just fine with "-std=C++11*"  -- Maybe g++ sees your extension as `.c` and uses the `C` compiler.  That is how Visual Studio works, and I wouldn't be surprised if g++ works that way also.  Second, you do realize that you can only use `malloc` on C types.  If you try to use `malloc` on C++ (non-POD) types, you are introducing undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, g++ indeed does work this way. It picks a compiler based on extension (which drives me mad, btw).

Comment: @SergeyA: But in C++, you should use `static_cast` which is not available in C anyway. The correct way is to compile both seperately and use interoperation headers. Apparently OP could use that, so it is the way to go. Now the question looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, compiling them separately seems like the best way to do this

Comment: @Olaf, my point exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it easier to use with macros:

```
#define e_new(type) ((type*)malloc(sizeof(type)))
#define e_new_array(type, count) ((type*)malloc((count)*sizeof(type)))
```

example usage:

```
graph_t *g = e_new(graph_t);
graph_t *ten_gs = e_new_array(graph_t, 10);
```

Note that this is *not* specific to your `e_malloc` - `malloc` itself has the same problem in C++.

Comment: That does not solve the problem you should use no cast at all in C and `static_cast` in C++.

Comment: @Olaf Kindly explain what problems the cast leads to in C in this case. Would you prefer `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#define e_new(type) ((type*)malloc(sizeof(type)))` `#else` `#define e_new(type) (malloc(sizeof(type)))` `#endif`? That would be pointless extra work for zero benefit whatsoever.

Comment: That has been discussed here 1000 times already. You very well should know. (And notice I used "should", not "shall" or "have to"). And no, I would prefer not to use `malloc` at all in C++. According to a comment of OP, he can use seperate files for C and C++, which is definitively the cleanest approach.

Comment: @Olaf The main reason is that it hinders readability and serves no purpose. Neither of which are issues in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler error clearly states, the error is in your calling code, not in your `e_malloc`.

You probably have something like this:

```
graph_t *g;
g = e_malloc(sizeof(graph_t));
```

The error is the type conversion between the `void *` returned by `e_malloc` and the expected `graph_t*`. Regular `malloc` shows the same behavior. You need to do the typecast explicitly:

```
g = (graph_t*)e_malloc(sizeof(graph_t));
```

Comment: yes, sorry if this wasn't clear, I know this already. My question is, 1) do I have to cast it every single time ? 2) is there any other option ? 3) how come it compiled just fine in Clion with Cmaker as a .cpp file with `"-std=c++11"`. I am trying to make a C and C++ compatible code at the moment

Comment: Yes you need to cast it every time.

Comment: @Shiro Yes, C++ requires the cast. C does not. If you want to write code that is valid as both C and C++ you need the cast, because C++ needs the cast. You can't use any fancy C++ features to make the cast unnecessary, because they won't work in C.

Comment: @immibis, and OP should not cast in C!

Comment: @SergeyA Explain to me why it's better to use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to include the cast when the code is compiled as C++ and not when it's compiled as C, rather than just including the cast anyway?

Comment: That does not solve the problem you should use no cast at all in C and `static_cast` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using this construct in C++ at all. In C++, you need to use `new`, not `malloc` - and `new` already throws an exception (by default). Problem solved.